# Java structure for set of sets that have to union? (for Kruskal's Algorithm)

Tags: java, set, kruskals-algorithm

I have to implement [Kruskal's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) in Java.

I have the part that I get the edges ordered by weight, but I am a little lost when I have to think the structure to save the sets of each tree.

I thought in having a vector of sets, where each sets represents a tree. But I don't know what to do if I have to union two trees. Delete both elements from the vector and add a new combined one?

Is there an structure that would make it easier?

What I need is:

- Iterate over all sets from a major set
- Add an element to one of the sets, or
- Create a new set and add it to the major set
- Union two of those sets (of course, deleting their singular versions)

Comment: It's difficult to assert that something does _not_ exist, but I have not come across a standard Java library implementation of this data structure. (You can use lists of lists, but that will make the algorithm rather slow). I presume that people have written implementations and made them available on the Web. If nothing else, the [disjoint set forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) is perhaps one of the simpler data structures to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The disjoint-set data structure that is referenced in the Wikipedia article you linked to in your question is the type of structure you need.  I'll suppose that you have a `Vertex` class in your implementation and give an example of what the "simple approach" might look like in Java, using an `ArrayList<Vertex>` to represent a set of vertices that form a connected component.

You would modify your `Vertex` class to look like

```
public class Vertex {

    // other data members
    private ArrayList<Vertex> component;

    public Vertex(/* arguments */) {
        // other initialization
        component = new ArrayList<>();
        component.add(this);
    }

    // other methods

    public ArrayList<Vertex> getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(ArrayList<Vertex> updatedComponent) {
        component = updatedComponent;
    }
}
```

This already satisfies the part of the algorithm that involves adding an element to a set, since the constructor takes care of creating the new component and adding the vertex to its own component.

To check whether two vertices `u` and `v` are in the same component you would use

```
if (u.getComponent() == v.getComponent()) {
    // they are in the same component
} else {
    // the components are different
}
```

and when you find that `u` and `v` are not in the same component, you could union the components with code like the following.

```
ArrayList<Vertex> larger;
ArrayList<Vertex> smaller;
if (u.getComponent().size() < v.getComponent().size()) {
    larger = v.getComponent();
    smaller = u.getComponent();
} else {
    larger = u.getComponent();
    smaller = v.getComponent();
}
for (Vertex aVtx : smaller) {
    aVtx.setComponent(larger);
}
larger.addAll(smaller);
```

I think that's all you would really need to implement Kruskal's algorithm correctly, but I have not addressed your comments about a major set.  If you wish to keep track of all of the components so that you can see what they look like at any point in the algorithm, this could be accomplished with a `HashSet<ArrayList<Vertex>> majorSet`.  As you constructed each vertex you could add the component to `majorSet`, and when you unite two components you would remove `smaller` from `majorSet`.  You could iterate over `majorSet.values()` in the standard fashion.

Comment: Hi Evan! Thank you, I thought something like this but I think the part of updating the components of the smaller set doesn't match the complexity required. Anyway, thank you so much, I will start from here.

Comment: You didn't state time complexity requirements in your question. In this solution each vertex sets its component at most log(n) times where n is the number of vertices because whenever you set the component of a vertex you at least double the size of the component that contains the vertex.  The time complexity could be improved if you use the more advanced form of the disjoint set data structure discussed in the Wikipedia article.  I don't know of a core Java implementation of that data structure.